# How to receive RTP audio stream Android?

Tags: java, android, audio, streaming, rtp

I am using Java to stream rtp audio from the microphone to my android phone app, but I am not hearing any sound. There are no errors when settings up the AudioGroup and AudioStream so I assume everything is going correctly. Here is the code on the app side:

```
    AudioStream audioStream;
    AudioGroup audioGroup;
    AudioCodec codec = AudioCodec.PCMU;
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audio.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
    audioGroup = new AudioGroup();
    audioGroup.setMode(AudioGroup.MODE_NORMAL);
    InetAddress inetAddress;
    try {
        inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("163.11.62.208");
        audioStream = new AudioStream(inetAddress);
        audioStream.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_RECEIVE_ONLY);
        audioStream.setCodec(codec);


        InetAddress inetAddressRemote = InetAddress.getByName("163.11.169.206");
        audioStream.associate(inetAddressRemote, 5004);
        audioStream.join(audioGroup);
    }
```

The ffmpeg stream test I use (which works on vlc Android player) is

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i aevalsrc="sin(400*2*PI*t)" -ar 8000 -vcodec pcm_u8 -f rtp rtp://163.11.62.208:5004
```

Again.. This works in VLC android player but not in my app. No errors.. Just no audio.

Ok I just noticed in LogCat that I am getting messages telling me that it is working. Here are some of the logs.

```
stream[59] is configured as RAW 8kHz 32ms mode 0
D/AudioGroup﹕ stream[59] joins group[56]
group[56] switches from mode 0 to 1
stream[54] joins group[56]
getOutputSamplingRate() reading from output desc
V/AudioSystem﹕ getSamplingRate() streamType 0, output 2, sampling rate 48000
V/AudioSystem﹕ getFrameCount() streamType 0, output 2, frameCount 960
V/AudioSystem﹕ getLatency() streamType 0, output 2, latency 160
V/AudioTrack﹕ getMinFrameCount=1280: afFrameCount=960, minBufCount=8, afSampleRate=48000, afLatency=160
D/AudioGroup﹕ reported frame count: output 1280, input 320
D/AudioGroup﹕ adjusted frame count: output 1280, input 512
V/AudioTrack﹕ sampleRate 8000, channelMask 0x1, format 1
V/AudioTrack﹕ streamType 0
V/AudioTrack﹕ set() streamType 0, sampleRate 8000, format 1, frameCount 1280, flags 0000
V/AudioSystem﹕ getLatency() streamType 0, output 2, latency 160
V/AudioSystem﹕ getFrameCount() streamType 0, output 2, frameCount 960
V/AudioSystem﹕ getOutputSamplingRate() reading from output desc
V/AudioSystem﹕ getSamplingRate() streamType 0, output 2, sampling rate 48000
V/AudioTrack﹕ createTrack_l() output 2 afLatency 160
V/AudioTrack﹕ afFrameCount=960, minBufCount=8, afSampleRate=48000, afLatency=160
V/AudioTrack﹕ minFrameCount: 1280, afFrameCount=960, minBufCount=8, sampleRate=8000, afSampleRate=48000, afLatency=160
V/AudioRecord﹕ sampleRate 8000, channelMask 0x10, format 1
V/AudioRecord﹕ inputSource 7
V/AudioRecord﹕ set(): sampleRate 8000, channelMask 0x10, frameCount 512
D/AudioRecord﹕ set(): voiceActivationState 0
D/AudioRecord﹕ Keep input Source type.
V/AudioRecord﹕ AudioRecord::set() minFrameCount = 320
V/AudioRecord﹕ set(): mSessionId 1827
V/AudioSystem﹕ ioConfigChanged() event 3, ioHandle 1828
```

BUT: I also just noticed that I get no system volume at all when running my app. When I change system volume it usually makes an indicator noise to show how loud/quiet that is but I'm hearing nothing. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Do not request strict mode to turn off networking.  It won't work at all on modern devices, and its likely the cause of problems.  If you need to do networking, use a thread or AsyncTask.

Comment: Ok I have changed that but I still seem to get no volume. I also moved the code into a separate thread.

Comment: Bump. Having the same problem here... If i try to `setMode` from MODE_RECEIVE_ONLY from MODE_SEND_ONLY, I get `IllegalStateException: busy` :(

Comment: Alright, `IllegalStateException` fixed, but still no loopback sound from server.

Comment: @TylerHelmuth Any luck resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've got `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />` in your manifest.

I'm betting you probably already do, so go to `Settings -> Apps -> (Click the Gear) -> App Permissions -> Microphone` and make sure it's switched on for your app.

It took me a very long time to figure this out as I was having the same issue with the permission in the manifest.